# Python 2.7 grammar not correct in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

So I'm trying to set up Eclipse for Python use.

I downloaded the 64 bit Eclipse, 64-bit Java SDK environment, and the PyDev extension for Eclipse.

I've been trying to follow this particular tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CryTwaJGpPM

I am using Python's 2.7 grammar yet my print statement (print p) is saying invalid syntax and works if I use Python 3.0 grammar [print (p)]

The following screenshots outlining the run config, interpreter, grammar version I'm using, and output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k1fS.jpg

Any idea on why it's enforcing the 3.0 grammar?

I would like to use 2.7 or 2.6.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you using the 3.4 version of Python in all of your references if you actually want 2.x? It's not the grammar that's a problem, *it's when you run it*.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at your screenshot of the run configuration. All of your paths are set to C:\Python34. Change them to your Python 2 directory, so you'll be using the correct (Python 2) libraries.

Also, look at your last screenshot: you may have Python 2 selected as your grammar, but you've configured it to use your Python 3.4 interpreter when it actually executes. Change your interpreter setting to wherever your Python 2 interpreter is and it will execute your scripts with that interpreter instead.